# FBLoginView with Parse to "Login with Facebook"

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am using FBLoginView for my app to handle logging in with Facebook but I am also using Parse.com. I am struggling to figure out how I can create a new user in Parse if I don't login using Parse's PFFacebookUtils class. Does anyone know a good way to use FBLoginView with parse to achieve "Login with Facebook"?

Answer (score 1):

Parse actually takes all the legwork out of this process by providing Facebook integration and a login view automatically for you. You can use Parse's built-in Facebook login system like so:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
    }
}];
```

When do you do this, 4 things will happen:

1. The user is shown the Facebook login dialog.
2. The user authenticates via Facebook, and your app receives a callback using handleOpenURL.
3. Parse SDK receives the Facebook data and saves it to a PFUser. If it's a new user based on the Facebook ID, then that user is created.
4. Your code block is called with the user.

You can find a solid step-by-step in the documentation here: 
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS